# Looking for a class name and a potential general solution

Tags: differential-geometry, harmonic-functions

Is there a standard class name if any of the following differential equation there similar to  Laplace equation and equivalent solution based on legendre polynomial, or spherical harmonics?

$\partial^2\ u/\partial\ x^2\ +\partial^2\ u/  \partial\ y^2\ +(1/v) \partial\ u/\partial\ t\ +k\ast\ u-c=0$

v,k and c are real constants